# Recoding in R and making between group comparisons

Tags: r, group-by, subset, recode

I have a dataframe with a column that has "Yes", "No" and "Maybe" values. Here is a sample of how the dataframe looks like for context (not actual data I'm working with as that's more sensitive):

| State | City | Do you like the color Blue? | Yes | Maybe | No |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Arizona | Phoenix | Yes | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Arizona | Phoenix | Yes | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Arizona | Phoenix | Maybe | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Arizona | Phoenix | No | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Arizona | Scottsdale | No | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Arizona | Scottsdale | Yes | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Arizona | Scottsdale | Maybe | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| California | San Francisco | Yes | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| California | San Francisco | No | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| California | San Francisco | Maybe | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| California | Los Angeles | Yes | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| California | Los Angeles | Yes | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| California | Los Angeles | No | 0 | 0 | 1 |

This is a two part question:

1. I would like to convert the "Yes" and "Maybe" in the "**Do you like the color Blue?**" column to equal 1 and the "No" to equal 0 (so categorical to numeric) and add it as a separate column.
2. I want to also make between states statistical comparisons as well (e.g. proportion of those who said "No" in California versus in Arizona). I was thinking of subsetting the data set by state and then making the comparisons, but the data set I'm working with has about 15 states. Is there a faster/more efficient way to do so?

Comment: OK I think I got the first question down using recode! I just need assistance with the second question.

Comment: Please check the solution below

Answer (score 0):

We may do this easily with `model.matrix` from `base R`

```
df1[c("Maybe", "No", "Yes")] <- model.matrix(~ df1$Do_you_like_the_color_Blue - 1)
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(new_col = +(Do_you_like_the_color_Blue == "Yes")) %>%
    group_by(State) %>%
    mutate(Prop = mean(!new_col)) %>%
    ungroup
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(State = c("Arizona", "Arizona", "Arizona", "Arizona", 
"Arizona", "Arizona", "Arizona", "California", "California", 
"California", "California", "California", "California"), City = c("Phoenix", 
"Phoenix", "Phoenix", "Phoenix", "Scottsdale", "Scottsdale", 
"Scottsdale", "San Francisco", "San Francisco", "San Francisco", 
"Los Angeles", "Los Angeles", "Los Angeles"), Do_you_like_the_color_Blue = c("Yes", 
"Yes", "Maybe", "No", "No", "Yes", "Maybe", "Yes", "No", "Maybe", 
"Yes", "Yes", "No"), Yes = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Maybe = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), No = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L
))
```

Answer (score 0):

To create the columns, we can use the `fastDummies` package, wich is usually much faster to write than recode or pivoting wider

```
library(fastDummies)
library(dplyr)

df %>% dummy_cols(`Do you like the color Blue?`)
```